# Ordered list from elements of a 2 dimensional list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a 2 dimensional list. Example:

```
list = [[1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9]]
```

I need to make a new list whose elements are the elements of each sub-element preserving the order.

Example:

```
final_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: `final_list = sorted(list_1 + list_2 + list_3)`?

Comment: Is the roundrobin recipe from `itertools`, what you are looking for? See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: No 8 in final_list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q:** The new list must take the first element of each list first, then the
>   second, and so on..

---

**A:**
You can use `zip` and a list comprehension.

```
list_1 = [1,4,7]
list_2 = [2,5,8]
list_3 = [3,6,9]


print([x for lst in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3) for x in lst])
# outputs > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

For your new list, you could do the same, but first unpack the list with a `*`

```
new_list = [[1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9]]

print([x for lst in zip(*new_list) for x in lst])
# outputs > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @abccd this is exactly what I need it!

Answer (score 1):

first transpose the list matrix with [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) then chaining all the inner list together with [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

also rename variable list to lst, not a good practice to use builtin `list` as variable name

```
import itertools
lst = [[1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9]]
final_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*lst)))
# final_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```